# Lots of doubts abot the surface area of a cylinder.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I recently started to study parametric surfaces, and I come across this exercise that I try to solve but I have a lot of doubts reganding  the correctness of my resolution, and also I don't find similar examples on the internet.

I need to find the surface area of the cylinder $$x^{2} + y^{2} = 4x$$ bounded by z=0 and z+ x =4. The cylinder is centered at (2,0) with radius 2.

I made the parametrization $$<2+rcos(t) , rsen(t), 2-rcos(t)>$$ with r between 0 and 2, and t between 0 and 2π (First doubt : Is the parametrization right?)

Then, if everything is ok, I would proceed to do the formula of a surface area (I would not write the whole formula because I am very bad at MathJax). But you know, the double integral of the norm of the vector ("u") being "u" the cross product of the partial derivatives of the parametrization. The vector u in this case is (r,0,r) and the norm is $$\sqrt{2}r $$

Then, if everything is right, the area of the surface is the double integral

$$\int_0^{2π}\int_0^2\sqrt{2}*r^2 dθdr  $$

Is this resolution right? If not, can you help me? Thanks.

PS : I know that the cylinder bounded by the plane is half of the full cylinder. This is the main reason that I think this resolution is wrong.

Comment: No, the parametrization isn't right. If you sketch the circle that generates the cylinder on the $\;xy-\,$ plane, it's easy to see that $\;-\frac\pi2\le t\le \frac\pi2\;$, for one....and where did you take the $\;z-$ component from?

Comment: Hello. The plane that bounds the cylinder is z+x = 4. Its incorrect to say that z = x-4 then z = 2- rcos(t) ?

Comment: The answer is indeed the half of the area of a cylindre of radius $2$ and height $4$, $8\pi$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes, I know that fact. And the resolution I made gives me other result, that is the reason of my doubts regarding my resolution.

Comment: I know, I am confirming the value (that you didn't give).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us solve for

$$(x-2)^2+y^2=4,\\z\in[0,2-(x-2)].$$

in polar coordinates. We have

$$A=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2-2\cos\theta}\,dz\,2\,d\theta=2\int_0^{2\pi}(2-2\cos\theta)\,d\theta=8\pi$$ (the cosine term cancels out).

Comment: I have a question :  in the first double integral , the part "dz2dθ". Where does the number 2 comes from? Is the value of the radius?

Comment: @Ulises I think for the Jacobian.

Comment: @Ulises: yes, the element of area is $r\,d\theta\,dz$.

Comment: Just a question. You can actually solve for $\theta$ as $\frac{\pi}{3}$. Is that significant or no?

Comment: @Ulises: where did I change the order ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Then I have wrong? :-( Just a curiosity. Why $0\leq z \leq 1-(x-2)$?

Comment: $z$ it the quote (height) of the cylinder.

Comment: If you make the cylindrical substitutions for the given equation, you can get a value for $\theta$.

Comment: We are using cylindrical coordinates. We have a circumference and z is the altitude.

Comment: This one: $x^2+y^2=4x$

Comment: @Sebastiano: grr, what is given about $z$ ?

Comment: By substituting $x=r\cos{\theta}$, $y=r\sin{\theta}$

Comment: If you simplify this you reach $\frac{1}{2}=\cos{\theta}$

Comment: I was just wondering if it was significant or not, as my original comment stated

Comment: @CSquared: I meant expand your computation.

Comment: $(x-2)^2+y^2=4(\cos{\theta}-1)^2+4\sin^2{\theta} = 4 $,,,   $\cos^2{\theta}-2\cos{\theta}+1+\sin^2{\theta}= 3-2\cos{\theta}=1$

Comment: I thought $r=2$

Comment: Wow. I feel dummy stupid

Comment: @CSquared: we are all subject to such confusions. But think that if both $r$ and $\theta$ are constant, you don't have a curve.

Comment: That's why I was confused. Thanks for being understanding

Comment: @CSquared: hope you didn't mind I let you understand by yourself.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Sorry for asking again , but the 2 stands for the cross product of the vectors?

Comment: @Ulises: vectors ? What vectors ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust  I ask because the formula in my original post (the double integral of the norm of the cross product blah blah). If you take the parametrization r(t,z) = (2+2cos(t), 2sen(t), z), the cross product of the partial derivatives of r is : (2cos(t), 2sen(t),0), and the norm of that is 2...

Comment: @Ulises: to establish the element of area, you use normalized vectors. The $2$ comes from the Jacobian.

Comment: You're right. I didn't even read the question right. It was in the hypothesis. I'm sorry, don't be angry. :-(

Answer (score 2):

First, you want "the skin" of the cylinder, not all what is there "in its interior", so the part to parametrize is only that: the envelope, and thus you can get

$$r(u,v)=(2+2\cos u,\,2\sin u,\,\text{something})\;,\;\;\text{with}\;\;-\frac\pi2\le u\le \frac\pi2$$

Now, that "something" must "advance vertically" from $\;z=0\;$ (which is the fancy name of the $\;xy-$ plane), and up until the plane $\;x+z=4\iff z=4-x=2-2\cos u\;$ (of course, it's not exactly "vertically" since there's a slant plane cutting the cyclinder. Also observe the plane and the circle in the $\;z=0\;$ plane intersect on this plane...)

Give it a try now.